# How to change the sort order of existing and furture folders in Claws Mail?

Tags: email, sorting, default-settings, ordering, claws-mail

By default, my emails are sorted by date descending. I prefer to have all my folders sorted in an ascending order instead.

What should I do so that I can automatically switch all the existing and to-be-created folders to my desired order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved in two steps.

Remember to close Claws Mail before editing any files in `~/.claws-mail`.

### Change the sort order inside existing folders

Replace `sort_type="descending" sort_key="date"` with `sort_type="ascending" sort_key="date"` in `~/.claws-mail/folderlist.xml`.

### Change the default sort order for new folders

Replace `default_sort_type=1` with `default_sort_type=0` in `~/.claws-mail/clawsrc`.

---

#### References

- [[Users] Change sort order for all folders (http://lists.claws-mail.org)](http://lists.claws-mail.org/pipermail/users/2012-October/004094.html)